# Changing cursor style in Chrome fails when user is hovering over a link

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a strange problem that i'm seeing in Chrome.

I use an ajax callback to set the cursor's css style to "wait" when a sidebar link is clicked. This works perfectly in firefox, but on Chrome the cursor style only changes when I hover away from the link - i.e. the style doesn't change whilst the user is still hovered over the link

What am I doing wrong?  Here's the relevant code:

```
// beforeSend callback
$('.ajax-link').bind('ajax:beforeSend', function() {
  $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
  $('a').css('cursor', 'wait');  
  $('article.post').addClass('loading');    
});

// success callback    
$('.ajax-link').bind('ajax:success', function() {
  $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
  $('a').css('cursor', 'pointer');  
  $("article.post").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @post) %>");
});
```

As you can see I am explicitly setting the css for all anchors too with `$('a').css('cursor', 'wait');` so that it works in firefox but Chrome doesn't seem to take notice of this.

Comment: Testing this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/HMfzL/ with Chrome 12.0.742.9 dev-m / Windows 7, it works properly for me - there's no bug. What version are you using? Perhaps it's been fixed? (or my test is flawed)

Comment: You're right, it looks like the bug has been fixed in newer versions of Chrome. I've just tested in a dev build and it's working properly. Thanks, that's a big relief.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, it's a Chrome and Safari bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26723

not much I can do about it, I guess I can just live with it