# What is the Javascript for changing the css on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JSFiddle example I can't get working:
http://jsfiddle.net/bjacobs/KDVvN/28/

I want the element to have an open hand when moused over (which works) and a closed hand when the mouse is clicked on it (which I can't get to work).

I know I am doing something wrong in the javascript. Can anyone help?

Javascript:

```
  $(function () {
    $(".dragbox h2").on("mousedown", function (evt) {
        $(this).addClass('grabbing');
    }).on("mouseup", function (evt) {
        $(this).removeClass('grabbing');
    });
  });
```

CSS:

```
.dragbox {
    margin:0px 2px 2px;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
}
.dragbox h2 {
    font-size:15px;
    cursor: grab;
    cursor:-webkit-grab;
    cursor:-moz-grab;
    cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/openhand.cur), default !important;
}
.dragbox h2.grabbing {
    cursor: grabbing;
    cursor:-webkit-grabbing;
    cursor:-moz-grabbing;
    cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/closedhand.cur), default !important;
}
```

Comment: To start, your fiddle does not include jQuery. Look in the browser's JavaScript console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: Is the element in question an `<h2>` element with all three of the following classes applied to it:  `column` `dragbox` `grabbing`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to remove column.

Comment: Your current solution will cause all `<h2>` tags within `dragbox` classed containers to receive the `grabbing` class. You probably want to change the event handlers to use `$(this).addClass(...)`, etc

Comment: Matt - Not sure what you mean, it tells me my javascript is valid. Phil - thanks I changed that. Still not working though.

Comment: If you changed `.on("mouseup"...` to `.bind("mouseleave mouseup"...` as in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KDVvN/22/), would this produce the desired behaviour?

Comment: The open hand works and the closed hand works. What doesn't work is switching between the two on a mouse event. I tried this in Firefox, Chrome, and IE.

Comment: I see, sorry it worked on my version of firefox (18.01)

Comment: Lello, that did work in Firefox and IE, but not Chrome.

Comment: ... and you are clicking your mouse button when on top of the `<h2>` element?  Are you sure your mouse is still over the `<h2>` element when you release the mouse button?

Comment: YES! Jahroy...when I clicked a different spot, Lello Three's suggestion worked! Lello, can you move your comment into the answer section?

Comment: I think the problem is that these cursor styles cannot be applied to a `<h2>` element.  Your code works fine for me if I debug it using FireBug... I can see the style being added and removed.  Also note that the class will **ONLY** be removed if the mouse is *still* over the text when the mouse button is released.

Comment: Wait, I can't get it to work in Chrome again. I thought it worked but now it's not.  Also, why do you use bind on mouseup but not mousedown?

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome (with the exact code listed above).  Are you using a debugger at all?  My debugger tells me that the JavaScript works fine, but the css does not.  In other words, I can see the style named "_grabbing_" being added and removed from the `<h2>` element in the debugger, but I cannot see the cursor changing its appearance.  **What do you see in your debugger??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not work with text elements. Try button (but obviously you have to start dragging to make it work):

**You can do this with just html/css**

**DEMO HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/KDVvN/37/**

HTML

```
<button>Test Grab!</button>
```

CSS

```
button {
    font-size:15px;
    cursor: grab;
    cursor:-webkit-grab;
    cursor:-moz-grab;
    cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/openhand.cur), default !important;
}
button:active {
    cursor: grabbing;
    cursor:-webkit-grabbing;
    cursor:-moz-grabbing;
    cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/closedhand.cur), default !important;
}
```

**Or JS**

**DEMO HERE: (http://jsfiddle.net/KDVvN/36/)**

HTML

```
<button>Test Grab!</button>
```

CSS

```
button {
    font-size:15px;
    cursor: grab;
    cursor:-webkit-grab;
    cursor:-moz-grab;
    cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/openhand.cur), default !important;
}
button.grabbing {
    cursor: grabbing;
    cursor:-webkit-grabbing;
    cursor:-moz-grabbing;
    cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/closedhand.cur), default !important;
}
```

JS

```
$("button").on("mousedown", function (evt) {
    $(this).addClass('grabbing');
}).on("mouseup", function (evt) {
    $(this).removeClass('grabbing');
});
```

Comment: This works great. So how can I find which elements it will work on besides button?  Preferably elements that you don't have to drag to get the closed hand to show up.

Comment: Well I'm not 100% sure but I think it wont work with text elements. And there's also a problem with browser forced cursors. For example when you are trying to drag image it will turn to "not-allowed". Use button you can do pretty much everything with button. Just overwrite default styles (border, background etc) http://jsfiddle.net/KDVvN/38/

Comment: Thanks so much. I wish there was a way to find out which other elements it would work on (and why), but Google has turned up nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Read this article:
http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-cursor-styles/

Maybe you missed some "," at '.column .dragbox h2.grabbing'
Only webkit browsers will support grabbing hand. But when i tried to use this in a similar way, i noticed that i cant make a closed hand cursor while grabbing, because the browser overrides it.

Comment: Please don't use links as the main content of your answer.  If that site ever goes away, this answer becomes much less valuable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in the sentence "Maybe you missed some "," at '.column .dragbox h2.grabbing'".  FYI, I tried this in Firefox, Chrome, and IE.  The open hand works and the closed hand works. What doesn't work is switching between the two on a mouse event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your JavaScript.

If I copy your code exactly and create my own test page, it works.

The style "*grabbing*" is added and removed from my `<h2>` element.

I can see the style being added and removed in FireBug.

The problem is, the cursor does not change.

This makes me think one of two things is true:

1. your css is not correct
2. these cursor styles cannot be applied to an `<h2>` element (or they cannot be applied when the mouse is over text)

Try opening up a debugger and you'll probably see the same thing.

My guess is that certain cursors only work in certain places on certain browsers...

Maybe you'll find something in one of these articles that explains what you're seeing:

- [Changing cursor style in Chrome fails when user is hovering over a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046935/changing-cursor-style-in-chrome-fails-when-user-is-hovering-over-a-link)
- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html
- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26723

Comment: I do see the style being added and removed in the debugger.  I've tried adding it to dragbox as well with no success. It doesn't matter if I'm over the text or not.  Inside the CSS block isn't wrong b/c if I put it in the .dragbox h2 CSS block I see the closed hand. Is the declaration of the block wrong? Is .dragbox h2.grabbing not the way to do it?